# Verify the identities

Tags: trigonometry

I want to verify the following identities:

$$({\sin^2\alpha-\cos^2\alpha\over \sin^2\alpha\cos^2\alpha})( {-\sin^3\alpha\over \cos\alpha -\sin\alpha})( {1-\sin^2\alpha \over \sin\alpha}) = \sin\alpha + \cos\alpha$$

I transformed a bit the first member – the second one looks fine.

$$({(\sin\alpha-\cos\alpha)(\sin\alpha+\cos\alpha)\over \sin^2\cos^2\alpha}) ({-\sin\alpha^3\over \cos\alpha -\sin\alpha})( {(1-\sin\alpha)(1+\sin\alpha) \over \sin\alpha}) = \sin\alpha + \cos\alpha$$

I can't really figure out how to continue to transform the first one. Any hints?

Comment: It should be $\sin^3\alpha$, rather than $\sin\alpha^3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that $1-\sin^2\alpha=\cos^2\alpha$, which cancels with the denominator of the first fraction; also $\sin^3\alpha$ cancels with the denominators of the first and third fractions. Thus you have
$$
\frac{-(\sin^2\alpha-\cos^2\alpha)}{\cos\alpha-\sin\alpha}
$$
and an elementary identity makes you finish up.

Comment: Magical. Thanks!

Comment: @Cesare Be careful, anyway: $1-\sin^2\alpha\ne(1-\sin^2\alpha)(1+\sin^2\alpha)$.

Comment: My bad, I edited my question. Thanks.